# is it possible to run Omnetpp IDE in m1 based Mac?

Tags: omnet++

I used all commands as in omnetpp installation guide (https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf) and also according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389105/installing-omnet-on-m1-macbook). The  `$ make` command worked and I also verified installation with:

```
$ cd samples/aloha
$ ./aloha
```

which started using qtenv.
but the problem is that the `$ omnetpp` command doest work with after printing

```
Starting the OMNeT++ IDE...
```

and eclipse IDE does not open.
is it possible to use this IDE in m1 Macs?
is there any alternate IDEs to workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify what version of OMNeT++ you were trying to run. I'm assuming 5.6.

OMNeT++ 5.6 relies on the system-wide installed JRE to run the IDE. That may NOT be present on your system if you are running on ARM. OMNeT++ 6 and 5.7 comes with a built-in private JRE, so the IDE should work with those versions also in intel emulation mode.

Comment: yes, your assumption was right. I am sorry for not prior mentioning. I tried with 5.7 version and it worked. Thank you.