# omnet++ debugging error on macbook M1 processor, 'Could not determine GDB version using command: lldbmi2 --version'

Tags: omnet++

I am using omnet++ v.6.0 (on MacBook pro with an m1 processor) and the debugger gives me the following error:

> Could not determine GDB version using command: lldbmi2 --version dyld
> [4595]: Library not loaded: @ rpath / LLDB.framework / LLDB
> Referenced from:
> /Users/gerald/Desktop/TESI/omnetpp-6.0/tools/macos.x86_64/bin/lldbmi2
> Reason: tried:
> '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/LLDB'
> (no such file),
> '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/LLDB'
> (no such file ), '/Library/Frameworks/LLDB.framework/LLDB' (no such
> file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/LLDB.framework/LLDB' (no such file)

Can you please help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after solving this part, there is another problem of the debugger attaching. Getting error message: "Waiting for debugger to start up and attach to us; note that for the latter to work, some systems (e.g. Ubuntu) require debugging of non-child processes to be explicitly enabled."  For the debugger issue: After compiling Omnet++ under x86 emulation on the M1/M2 (see [Installing OMNeT++ on M1 MacBook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389105/installing-omnet-on-m1-macbook)) you should have lldbmi2 in the tools/macOS.x86_64/bin folder of where you made Omnet++.  If for any reason this is not the case you can install it using: "brew install gdb". This will need to be under x86 emulation also, as it will not install with native M1/M2. Once you can determine from the command line: "lldbmi2 --version" you can place the absolute path name in Omnet++ under "General settings for GDB Debugging->GDB debugger"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).